# Parsing CSV with Multiple Header Rows

Tags: javascript, json, csv, vue.js

I'll start by saying "I did not format this data this way!" and I am not happy to have to work with it...but need some guidance on if this is even possible as I don't control the source. I've tried looking through papa-parse, csv-parser, and some other posts but coming up nil.

I've got a CSV that's formatted with multiple header rows like the following:

```
FOLDER,C:\DATA\STUFF\XYZ,"STUFF",XYZ
"STUFF1.txt","06/30/2015 13:46:42",930124,5.0
"STUFF2.txt","06/30/2015 13:46:42",930124,5.0
FOLDER,C:\DATA\STUFF2\XYZ2,"STUFF2",XYZ2
"STUFF21.txt","06/30/2015 13:46:42",930124,5.0
"STUFF22.txt","06/30/2015 13:46:42",930124,5.0
FOLDER,C:\DATA\STUFF3\XYZ3,"STUFF2",XYZ3
"STUFF31.txt","06/30/2015 13:46:42",930124,5.0
"STUFF32.txt","06/30/2015 13:46:42",930124,5.0
```

My though is parsing the file from the first folder entry until it reaches the next folder entry, and that is all `C:\DATA\STUFF\XYZ` files, then from the next "FOLDER" entry to the next, and those are all `C:\DATA\STUFF2\XYZ2` files. I guess my ideal output would be in JSON like:

```
{
    "folders": {
        "C:\\DATA\\STUFF\\XYZ": [{
                "name": "STUFF1.txt",
                "modified": "06/30/2015 13:46:42",
                "data": "930124",
                "additonal": "5.0"
            },
            {
                "name": "STUFF2.txt",
                "modified": "06/30/2015 13:46:42",
                "data": "930124",
                "additonal": "5.0"
            }
        ],
        "C:\\DATA\\STUFF\\XYZ2": [{
                "name": "STUFF21.txt",
                "modified": "06/30/2015 13:46:42",
                "data": "930124",
                "additonal": "5.0"
            },
            {
                "name": "STUFF22.txt",
                "modified": "06/30/2015 13:46:42",
                "data": "930124",
                "additonal": "5.0"
            }
        ],
        "C:\\DATA\\STUFF\\XYZ3": [{
                "name": "STUFF31.txt",
                "modified": "06/30/2015 13:46:42",
                "data": "930124",
                "additonal": "5.0"
            },
            {
                "name": "STUFF32.txt",
                "modified": "06/30/2015 13:46:42",
                "data": "930124",
                "additonal": "5.0"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is this a valid approach? Am I missing a better way to handle it?

Comment: It is no valid CSV file. But you can convert it, if the indicator FOLDER at the start of the lines persists. You just have to use this to trigger the creation a new child object and add the data rows to the last created object.

Comment: @Christopher yeah I thought about this over the weekend, it seems like best bet is to not try and treat it like CSV. I'm about 50% of the way with writing a solution to read it in as a file line by line and created the objects from there. Thanks for kind of guiding me in that direction.